# Nagarjuna on the mind body problem?

Tags: buddhism

So I understand the physicists framing of casuality as follows: given an initial value of a system, say a cart on a piece of land. I add a fictitious (and privileged) initial condition, say a push. Then I say I calculate the force on the cart. And then I make statements like if I hadn't pushed the cart, it wouldn't have moved. Cause precedes effect, blah blah blah.

What blew me away was in "Part Two, Chapter one - Examination of Conditions" of the book the fundamental wisdom of the middle way - Jay L Garfield, Nagarjuna argues against such privileged fiction and concludes in dependent arising of phenomena.

Now, while I haven't completely read the book. The western thought then gives motive of seperating mental events from physical and perhaps a notion of language where we explore the fiction of our minds.

With such a starting point how did the Buddhists solve(/think of) the mind body problem?

Comment: The push is fictitious. Maybe even privileged. But so is the cart.

Comment: The native American Whorfian Dan 'Moonhawk' Alford has some interesting writings on how European languages with subject-object structures create the illusion of inevitability of predicates that 'hang onto' subjects.  [See](https://glennaparicioparry.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/moonhawk-fetzer-dialogues.pdf). More [generally](https://glennaparicioparry.com/dan-moonhawk-alford/).  The well known example from Whorf is that the English sentence *The light flashed* suggests that the light is different from the flash.  Whorf argues that this is not an intrinsic of the world but a superimposition

Comment: The book called the Abhidharma is probably the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no mind. So there is no mind/body problem. Everything is a product of Pratitya Samputpada (dependent origination). I could rattle on about it ad nauseum. So you tell me, if there is something else that you want to know. True self is no self.

Comment: Perhaps if you could elaborate on "True self is no self."

Comment: @MoreAnonymous [anatta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatt%C4%81) is a core Buddhist idea.

Comment: Mind-oriented people are prone to shock when they see through this particular illusion. Remember the story of the Arhats who finally realized shunyata?

Comment: If you read a bit about Nagarjuna or about Buddhism, in general, you will quickly come to find that they believe that the ultimate reality is “empty of self-existence”. Everything arises and passes away and that there is no permanent self that travels through time. Hence, one of their main problems is explaining why it seems to.

Comment: "There is no Bodhi-tree
Nor stand of a mirror bright.
Since all is emptiness
Where can the dust alight?"

Answer (score 2):

The Abhidharma is dualist, and Nagarjuna would have been aware of that. Nagarjuna denies that either mind or body have substance - "svabhava". According to the Buddhist canon, the Yogacara masters Vasubandhu and his older brother Aryadeva then arrived and proved "mind only", as a panacea for the nihilism of what would later be developed into "Madhyamaka" (you are probably reading a translation of a translation of a translation of Nagarjuna). However, like the zen narrative of transmission to Bohidharma (through all of these monks) in general, modern history says this is mistaken - Yogacara predates Nagarjuna.

This is well known. Working out how "Emptiness" relates to substance dualism is a philosophical and comparative problem, one which probably has little scholarship on, as substance dualism is not very fashionable.

Comment: long winded way of saying idrk but yeah

Comment: Yes. The Buddha said that there are different ways to teach different people, and for some, you have to exhaustively go through dualism to its absurd conclusions to show them Nonduality. I find an experimental approach better, but it is hard to set it up, and non-repeatable, and impossible to explain. I met someone who could talk people into satori, but that's unusual.